# Event Viewer - how to read information

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, crash, r, event-viewer

I'm dealing with a situation in which a Windows 10 machine is restarting (or freezing after logon) randomly. It seems that a disk may be the culprit (source is NTFS). However, I could not find how to identify the drive based on Event Viewer data.

It reads, for instance:

```
\\?\Volume{616e5743-0000-0000-00a0-69da1b000000}
```

How to relate that information to a specific drive? That `Volume{xxxx}` info has already appeared more than once. Looking into the registry, that string appears a number of times but no clue about the physical item.

P.S. `chkdsk /f` for all drives is OK. Earlier, Windows corrected errors on a drive (not the system one) at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following options should help:

- Run `mountvol.exe` from a command line.
- Copy and paste the path `\?\Volume{616e5743-0000-0000-00a0-69da1b000000}\` in to the run box and it will open the drive in question.
- Correlate the drive with the Volume ID in the registry under `HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`
- Run the powershell command `GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume`
- Run the powershell command `get-volume | select *`

If you suspect a drive is having trouble, then `chkdsk /f` is not the command to use to find out. Instead you should use `chkdsk /r` to perform a full surface scan to check the integrity of the drive. This has some risks of making things worse.

However, there are better, third party tools for performing drive diagnostics similar to `chkdsk /r` without as much risk of doing additional damage to the drive. Examples are SeaTools, WD Life Guard, HDDScan, HDD Regenerator, etc.

Regardless, your first task should always be to recover and backup any data you need, before further stressing the drive.

Comment: Please clarify... are you advising OP to use `chkdsk /r` or *not* to use it?

Comment: @freginold done.